# Why port is blocked (local windows network)

Tags: windows, netstat

I have two windows computers at my house

- 10.0.0.15: main computer.
- 10.0.0.1: laptop

My laptop is running an application on port 6000 that I want to access from the main computer.

I have connection from my computer to the laptop. I can do VNC, and access files in both directions.

But for some reason I am getting "connection refused" when trying to connect to the application running on port 6000.

Actually, even from within the laptop, I can't telnet it using its own ip (10.0.0.1). Tried also with powershell Test-NetConnection.

I also tried disabling completely the firewall on the laptop, and opening port 6000 in the router.

[image]

See image above:

1. ipconfig result, showing ip of laptop computer is 10.0.0.1
2. netstat result, showing that port 6000 is listening
3. TestConnection for localhost:6000, with success
4. TestConnection for 10.0.0.1:6000, showing TcpTestSucceeded is false.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your question is off topic, but you are only listening on the loopback interface, not on the interface of your network card.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. It was an issue in the app, causing it to listen specifically on the loopback. Thanks

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, it is unclear to me how this question is off topic. perhaps you are refering to the SF TOS instead of SU's?

Comment: @justadev, that is correct. your application is configured to listen only on 127.0.0.1:6000. instead it should be bound to 0.0.0.0:6000 or 10.0.0.1:6000 in order to be accessible to other LAN hosts. most applications that establish listening ports provide a means to configure listening address or scope.  without knowing what application we can't help you any further, but if you search online for "<appllicationname> connect from LAN" or somesuch, you will probably find what you need.